# Custom control Windows phone application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create my custom control, but I am still getting error: The name "CustomCircleControl" does not exist in the namespace "using:App8"

My app namespace is App8 and class CustomCircleControl exists in it.
Errors appears in file Generic.xaml, but I do not understand why.

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App8">

<Style TargetType="local:CustomCircleControl"> -- This line is marked by visual studio as error (The name "CustomCircleControl" does not exist in the namespace), but intelisence knows class CustomCircleControl.
```

Thank you for any help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the namespace incorrectly.

The correct way to declare a namespace in XAML is the following:

```
xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:Your.Namespace.Here"
```

So in your case, it'll look like this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App8"
```